# Parse multiple values from SOAP response

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, soap

I have an XML SOAP response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <trk:TrackResponse xmlns:trk="http://www.web.com/XMLSchema/Track/v2.0">
      <trk:Package>
        <trk:Activity>
          <trk:ActivityLocation>
            <trk:Address>
              <trk:City>RUEMLANG</trk:City>
              <trk:CountryCode>CH</trk:CountryCode>
            </trk:Address>
          </trk:ActivityLocation>
        </trk:Activity>
        <trk:Activity>
          <trk:ActivityLocation>
            <trk:Address>
              <trk:City>BERLIN</trk:City>
              <trk:CountryCode>DE</trk:CountryCode>
            </trk:Address>
          </trk:ActivityLocation>
        </trk:Activity>
      </trk:Package>
    </trk:TrackResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to get the cities between `<trk:City>` but can't figure it out.
I have tried the below without any results

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('test.xml').getroot()
for element in e.findall('.//trk:City'):
    print (element.text)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use prefix for your namespaces.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('test.xml').getroot()
ns = {'trk':'http://www.web.com/XMLSchema/Track/v2.0'}

for element in e.findall('.//trk:City', ns):
    print (element.text)
```

prints

```
RUEMLANG
BERLIN
```